# Get Value of Textfield into PHP Variable without POST

Tags: php, variables, textfield

I need to get the value of a textfield and save it into a variable but without a submit button.

Like this here:
http://streambadge.com/

As you can see the text you write in step two will automatically be added to the output text.
How can I do this?

Comment: That doesn't use PHP. It's entirely client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by javascript /jquery (client site script).

**live Demo :**
http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/51/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="country" />
<div  id="needs" >You will have output here :</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
         $('input[id="country"]').on('keyup', function() {  // on keyup event in your input field
                $("#needs").append(this.value);// append values from input field
          });
    );
```

You want to save this value in a php variable then you need ajax call(without submitting your form) or you need to submit the form.

For basic ajax you can read this:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-post.htm

useful  jquery links to learn:
API documentation: http://api.jquery.com/

Basic : http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Thank you. I think this will help me.
But how do I save the value to a PHP variable? Oh, I don't need to do that. I can just change the filename of the included image with that :D

Comment: in this case you will need ajax or you need to submit form

Comment: Lets say I have `<img src="http://test.com/FILENAME.png" />` How can I change the filename with that script? As far as I see it can only fill things but can it place something at the end or in between?

Comment: try to learn the basic of javascript/jquery first then you can do it easily and you will have much much fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `onchange` or `onkeyup` to detect when a user is typing.